# Scheme: Define a recursive predicate u-even? takes a list, returns #t if the number of items in the list is even

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

This was a question on a test I had last week and I can't figure out how to do it, without converting to decimal which is what was asked.

Define a recursive predicate u-even? that takes a list ls representing a non-negative integer number in unary and returns #t if and only if the number is even. Do not convert the list into a decimal or use the decimal system. Recall that the only symbol that ls may contain is 'l (the first letter of the word "lion").

Works like this:

```
     `~ (u-even? '(l l))
       #t
       ~ (u-even? '(l l l))
       #f
       ~ (u-even? '(l l l l))
       #t
       ~ (u-even? '(l l l l l l l))
       #f
       ~ (u-even? '())
       #t`

        `(define u-even?
          (lambda (ls)
            (cond
               [(null? ls) #t]
               [else ;;I JUST DON'T KNOW PLEASE GIVE ME A HINT AT LEAST. `
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with this definition of `even`?

```
(define (even x)
  (if (zero? x)
      #t
      (not (even (- x 1)))))
```

This is a slighly faster version since it don't negate the answer in each iteration and that makes this tail recursive:

```
(define (even x)
  (cond ((zero? x) #t)
        ((= x 1) #f)
        (else (even (- x 2)))))
```

Now. Changing the argument from a number to a list makes you need to change your base cases.. eg. `(null? x)` instead of `(zero? x)` since `'()` is even, just like `0` is.

Can you guess how you check for a one element list without using `length`?

Comment: I think I got it
        (define u-even?
          (lambda (ls)
           (cond
              [(null? ls) #t]
              [else (not (u-even? (cdr ls)))])))

Comment: @StaciLThompson Thats correct. How about the second one? (It's the last one you would want to present in an assignment)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, the following function should work.

```
(define (u-even? l) 
  (define (helper in out) 
    (if (null? in) 
      out 
      (helper (cdr in) (not out)))) 
  (helper l #t))
```